# Powershell, rename-item doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a bunch of jpg image files named in the following pattern:

```
0001-rand01_012.jpg
0002-rand03_034.jpg
```

I want to rename them by removing the first 5 characters to get the form:

```
rand01_012.jpg
```

etc..

I use the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.Substring(5)}
```

When using this with -whatif flag i get the expected message saying:

```
Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\xx xx\temp2\0123-rand16_030.jpg Destination: C:\Users\
xxxx\Documents\xx xx\temp2\rand16_030.jpg".
```

But removing the `whatif` gives me errors of this type:

```
Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be 
larger than length of string.
```

followed by a whole bunch of:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

The files themselves are renamed with random number of characters removed rather than 5 as was intended. So they have ended up like:

```
01.jpg
01.jpg
.
.
.
d14_001.jpg
```

etc.

I have used this command to rename such files in the past with success. The fact that I'm getting such random results is making me pull my hair out.

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem) |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Substring(5)}`

Comment: sorry, why would it change the behavior?

Comment: @4c74356b41: It explicitly collects all matching files in an array first, before passing that array to `Rename-Item`. However, while that makes _conceptual_ sense (enumerate first, so that renamed files can't interfere with the enumeration), I don't think it's _technically_ necessary - see the footnote I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Make sure you only process the files of interest:

```
(Get-ChildItem -File [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-*.jpg) |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.Substring(5)} -WhatIf
```

<sup>The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.

In *PowerShell [Core] 6+*, placing `(...)` around `Get-ChildItem` is no longer *technically* necessary, but advisable.[1]</sup>

That way:

- You rule out unrelated files up front.
- Even if something goes wrong, you can correct the problem and run the command again to reprocess only the failed files, without affecting the previously renamed files.

  - The most likely reason for something going wrong is more than 1 input file resulting in the *same* filename after removing the 5 first char.

---

It sounds like you've mistakenly run the command *repeatedly*, so you've cut off 5 chars. *multiple times*:

`0001-rand01_01.jpg` -> `rand01_01.jpg` -> `_01.jpg`

Once a filename has fewer than 5 chars., you'll get the the `startIndex`-related error, because the `[string]` class's `.Substring()` method doesn't accept an index beyond the length of the string (try `'ab'.Substring(3)`).

**That said, since you're running `Get-ChildItem` without a filter and therefore return *all* (non-hidden) child items, you may be processing *unrelated files ore even directories* whose names are too short.**

The `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` errors are just follow-on errors that result from the script block that normally returns the new name effectively returning the empty string, so `Rename-Item` is somewhat obscurely complaining that you can't rename a file to its current name.

**That said, you can even get `Cannot create a file when that file already exists` errors during the *first* run, namely if more than 1 input file with its first 5 chars. chopped off results in the same filename.**

E.g., `0001-rand01_012.jpg` and `0002-rand01_012.jpg` would both be renamed to `rand01_012.jpg`, which *fails* once the first one has been renamed.

That is, **for your command to work as intended, all filenames that result from dropping the first 5 chars. must be unique.**

Here's an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

Setup:

```
# Create and change to temp dir.
Set-Location (mkdir temp)
# Create sample input files named 0001-rand01_01.jpg, 0002-rand01_02.jpg, ...
# Note how the suffixes after the first 5 char. must be *unique*.
1..9 | %{ $null > "000${_}-rand01_0${_}.jpg" }
```

1st run:

```
# No errors
> (Get-ChildItem -File) | Rename-Item  -NewName { $_.Name.Substring(5) }
# Show new names
> Get-ChildItem | Select Name

Name         
----         
rand01_01.jpg
rand01_02.jpg
rand01_03.jpg
rand01_04.jpg
rand01_05.jpg
rand01_06.jpg
rand01_07.jpg
rand01_08.jpg
rand01_09.jpg
```

A 2nd run yields:

```
Name    
----    
1_01.jpg
1_02.jpg
1_03.jpg
1_04.jpg
1_05.jpg
1_06.jpg
1_07.jpg
1_08.jpg
1_09.jpg
```

At the time of the 3rd run, all the names are too short, and all you'll get is `Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` errors.

---

<sup>[1] Enclosing `Get-ChildItem` in `(...)` ensures that the matching files are collected in an *array*, *up front*, before `Rename-Item` is invoked.

This explicitly prevents already-renamed files from getting re-enumerated by `Get-ChildItem` and thus interfering with the iteration.  Explicit use of `(...)` is *technically* no longer necessary in PowerShell [Core] 6+ (it *is* necessary in *Windows PowerShell* (5.1-)), because `Get-ChildItem` is *implemented* in a way that [*always* internally collects info about all files *up front*, across platforms](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c857392c34613fc8ece1432ceb89a5310d9e5fd9/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L1618), because it sorts them by name, which is inherently only possible after all names have been collected.

In light of that, whether you use `(...)` or not should *functionally* amount to the same, although using `(...)` is advisable, because it doesn't rely on what amounts to an *implementation detail* (the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-) doesn't mention how the outputs are ordered).</sup>