# Powershell script to add underscore at specific character of filename

Tags: powershell

I have a list of hundreds of files in a folder at path C:\Users\Files
The current files are all named with a leading ID number that is five digits and then continues with the rest of the filename and extension.
Using Powershell, I want to add an underscore after the 5th character for all files in this directory.

Before:  12345DocumentA.pdf

After:   12345_DocumentA.pdf

Any help or guidance is appreciated!
Thanks,
Jenn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue attempting to insert character into filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925177/issue-attempting-to-insert-character-into-filename)

Comment: Yes that answers my question thank you.  I did search for a bit of time before posting so I'm not sure why someone would mark me a minus for this post.  I thought asking questions is what this forum was about.

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to do this, but this is one:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.pdf' -File) |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d{5}[^_]+' } |              # name should start with 5 digits, NOT followed by an underscore
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^(\d{5})', '$1_' }
```

Comment: Thanks Theo. This probably does what I was wanting but someone provided a link to a previous post from someone else and I was able to make that work.  I really appreciate the help!